# Removing captcha before wordpress login

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, iframe

Received a website from a client and installed Wordpress/transferred files to recreate the site

Now before log-in, a CAPTCHA appears which my client "cannot bypass" to get into the back end of the site.

Wondering why this would be appearing here and how to get rid of it?

The following is the source code from the page the CAPTCHA appears on. Can provide more information.

```
<html><body><form method="post" action="wp-login.php"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LdLwd8SAAAAALft5whK9ZfINkT6vmTdF4iWgt5t"></script>

<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdLwd8SAAAAALft5whK9ZfINkT6vmTdF4iWgt5t" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript></form></body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This markup is what's putting the CAPTCHA there

```
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
```

Just remove it from insde the `<noscript>` tag to get rid of it

**EDIT** on second thought I can't tell but it looks like the link to the google url is what's bringing in the CAPTCHA. Maybe just remove the entire `<noscript>` tag.

Or... The `<script>` after `<form>` is what's doing it.

I'm just concerned that if you remove the `<noscript>` or the `<script>`, it may get rid of the whole log-in interface.

My 2cents

Comment: So the CAPTCHA just appears instead of the login page. Maybe a redirect? However, once you complete the CAPTCHA, it takes you to the appropriate WP login page.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using google chrome, you can right click...view the code running behind and search for captcha in the browser. You will see a long path with the term CAPTCHA, go back to your file explorer and search for that path. Delete it, Restart your server thingy and voila..CAPTCHA should be gone.
I am new to wordpress, I took my shot with my forged method and it worked.